# How to return a true value from dictionary mapping result in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, mapping

I have a method called process in the python program, This method has to perform arithmetic operations according to input operator.But this always returns None.

```
def process(self):
        switcher = {
            self.operator == Operator.PLUS : self.input1.process() + self.input2.process(),
            self.operator == Operator.MINUS : self.input1.process() - self.input2.process(),
            self.operator == Operator.MULT : self.input1.process() * self.input2.process(),
            self.operator == Operator.DIV : self.input1.process() / self.input2.process()
        }
        return switcher.get(self, "None")
```

When i debug the code,there are two values in the switcher variable.One is true and another is false.The true has the actual calculated value.How can i return only the true value?

Comment: That seems like a really bizarre way to approach this. `self` isn't any of the keys in the dictionary (there will only be two, `True` and `False`) and you have to do all four calculations even though you only want one result. The usual way to do this would be a mapping like `{Operator.PLUS: operator.add, ...}`, i.e. store the *operation* (see [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html)) not the *result*. Alternatively, *actually use the key `True`*.

Comment: As @jonrsharpe said - Your `switcher` looks like it will store a dictionary with 2 items using the keys `True` and `False`. And you're saying if `self` isn't a key within `switcher` then use the string `None`.

Comment: So is there any best practice to implement switch case rather than if/ elif ?

Comment: See my comment. At the very least, you need to use a key that's *actually in the dictionary*.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jonrsharpe